# I get a error message for something I din't write

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

Hello I try to make the player follow the mouse while the player points towards the mouse. For that to work I will need the position of the player. This is what I got so far

```
 pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
 xplayer_pos= player.get_rect().centerx
 yplayer_pos= player.get_rect().centery
 angle = 360-math.atan2(pos[1]-xplayer_pos[1],pos[0]-yplayer_pos[0])*180/math.pi       
 rotimage = pygame.transform.rotate(player,angle)
 rect = rotimage.get_rect(center=(xplayer_pos,yplayer_pos))
 screen.blit(rotimage,rect)
 screen.blit(rotimage,pos)
 pygame.display.update()
```

but I get this eror message

```
angle = 360-math.atan2(pos[1]-xplayer_pos[1],pos[0]-yplayer_pos[0])*180/math.pi
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I don't understand why I get this message cause in that lin I don't use anything like 'getitem'. thanks for your time.

Comment: Something is not what it is expected to be. I recommend you split up the big expression into the smallest parts possible (storing the result in temporary variables) and it will be much easier to locate where the problem might be.

Comment: You have `xplayer_pos= player.get_rect().centerx`, thus xplayer_pos is already a single (int) value, not a tuple (unliked `pos`). Ditto for yplayer_pos.

Comment: `[]` this is `__getitem__` in your code. It tries to get the item at the location you specified.

Comment: Please debug your program first: you could print all your variables on the various lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`player.get_rect().centerx` is an integer. `xplayer_pos[1]` makes no sense. (`__getitem__` refers to the `[` `]` operator.)